# How do i get the positive/negative bars on the second facet plot to color correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have the dataframe below where i add the column "Color" with red or green based on if 'netflow_USD' is positive or negative.

```
      date    netflow_total    coin   close      netflow_USD    Color
0   2022-07-27  59784.661988    eth 1636.451360 9.783469e+07    green
1   2022-07-26  232728.945946   eth 1449.334247 3.373020e+08    green
2   2022-07-25  126246.255448   eth 1440.557443 1.818650e+08    green
3   2022-07-24  56072.035139    btc1598.078740  8.960753e+07    green
4   2022-07-23  -16099.547813   btc 1548.982186 -2.493791e+07   red
```

When plotting with plotly express, i get this
[image]

here is the code for the chart:

```
fig = px.bar(data, x="date", y="netflow_USD",  facet_row="coin")
fig.update_traces(marker_color=data["Color"]) #reassign bar colors based on red / green column
fig.show()
```

The bars on the bottom chart are coloring based on the colors from the top chart, not the 'Color' column. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a glitch or a specification. To work around this, we use subplots to create bar graphs for data extracted by crypto asset name in the data frame. Since there are two crypto asset names in the data presented, I add a title for the y-axis of the second axis of the graph with a limit of two. The `fig.add_annotation()` line should be disabled because a different method is required when the number of crypto asset names increases.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

for i,c in enumerate(data['coin'].unique()):
    df = data.query('coin == @c')
    fig.add_bar(x=df['date'], y=df['netflow_USD'], marker=dict(color=df['Color']), row=i+1, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title=c, anchor='y2'))#yaxis=dict(title='netflow_USD'), 
    fig.add_annotation(x=1.005, y=0.25 if i == 1 else 0.75,
                       showarrow=False,
                       text=c,
                       textangle=90,
                       xanchor='left',
                       xref='paper',
                       yanchor='middle',
                       yref='paper',)
    
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(dtick='1D'),
                  yaxis=dict(title='netflow_USD'),
                  xaxis2=dict(dtick='1D'),
                  yaxis2=dict(title='netflow_USD'),
                 showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]